# How to tell NPM where to install a particular file?

Tags: npm, npm-install

Working in one folder, how should one tell npm to install to a different location? Initially I was thinking you could include a tag with the location. Documenting this because when I made the search I didn't see any answers readily available (possibly because the answer is pretty simple).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized it is quite simple - just cd into the directory you're wanting to install in and run the install command like usual.